# Importing Post from Database ID

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently creating a news blog and I want to show small clips of the blog and let the user click "Read More" if they want find out more info (see image below)

[image]

On the Read More button I have it linked like this.

```
<a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/notices/notice.php?id=<?=$image["id"] ?>">Read More</a>
```

Then on the notice.php page I'm trying to import the post in like this: (data base name is knollsnews)

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM knollsnews WHERE id='$id'");
while ($image=mysql_fetch_array($images))
{
?>
```

I'm not sure what I doing wrong here. The problem is that the post is not showing up on the notice.php page.

Here is the full code:

```
<?php


$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM knollsnews WHERE id='$id'");
while ($image=mysql_fetch_array($images))
{
    ?>
<li data-id="id-<?=$image["id"] ?>">
<article class="postwhite">
<h2 style="margin: 10px 0 !important;"><?=$image["title"] ?></h2>
<img alt="<?=$image["title"] ?>" src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/knolls_file_manager/source/NoticesImages/<?=$image["file_name"] ?>" class="img-max" title="<?=$image["title"] ?>">
<div class="newsdate" style="margin: 10px 0 !important;"><?= date("F d, Y", strtotime($image["date"])); ?></div>
<p class="articletext"><?=$image["description"] ?></p>
</article>
</li>
    <?php
}
?>
```

**Final Working CODE ON notice.php page**

```
 <?php
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM knollsnews WHERE id='$id'");
while ($image = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
?>

<li data-id="id-<?=$image["id"] ?>">
<article class="postwhite">
<h2 style="margin: 10px 0 !important;"><?=$image["title"] ?></h2>
<img alt="<?=$image["title"] ?>" src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/knolls_file_manager/source/NoticesImages/<?=$image["file_name"] ?>" class="img-max" title="<?=$image["title"] ?>">
<div class="newsdate" style="margin: 10px 0 !important;"><?= date("F d, Y", strtotime($image["date"])); ?></div>
<p class="articletext"><?=$image["description"] ?></p>
</article>
</li>

    <?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_array($result))

Comment: It's too simply... you haven't printed anything. Please post your full code.

Comment: Can't you just select everything and handle the rest in php/javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out, you have to use `$_GET['id']` to get the id param from the URL. Also, your while loop says

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM knollsnews WHERE id='$id'");
while ($image=mysql_fetch_array($images))
```

when it should say

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM knollsnews WHERE id='$id'");
while ($image = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

In addition to that, [your code is open to SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) if you do not [sanitize the input](http://php.net/filter_var) or change the query to use prepared statements. At the very minimum, use

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

to make sure the id really is a number and not some malicious SQL.

Also, you are using the old mysql extension which is [officially deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and will be removed from PHP soon. Consider using PDO or MySqli

Comment: Got it working. All I had to do was change.
`$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM knollsnews WHERE id='$id'");
while ($image = mysql_fetch_array($result))`

to this:

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM knollsnews WHERE id='$id'");
while ($image = mysql_fetch_array($result))`

Answer (score 1):

You ned to get value from URL and set it to $id:

```
$id= $_GET['id'];
```

and after that you have to do:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM knollsnews WHERE id='$id'");
while ($image=mysql_fetch_array($images))
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I've tried a few methods and still not getting the info on my notice.php page. Here is the code I'm currently using:

(See EDIT at TOP)

Answer (score 1):

To get the id from the URL use `$_GET['id']`